# Can't upload images in backend, buttons missing

Tags: image, backend, upload

Can someone please help? In the backend of my magento store the button allowing me to download/upload images has disappeared so I cannot upload new images for the products that I add. For exsiting products I can see the image on the frontend but no image is showing in the backend. Any ideas?

Comment: is there any error in the console,?

Comment: skin/adminhtml is default?

Comment: which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

First steps to check:

1. Make sure Flash is installed and up-to-date. You can check [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html). Plugins must be enabled on your browser too.
2. Make sure you have the folder `design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media`. It should have swf files. If not, copy this folder over from a fresh Magento install.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue check your domain settings, (if your flash is fine). Try changing your base/secure domains without www. and with, (www. caused my image buttons to not show). If you have multiple store views make sure you check all them.